# pandas dataframe filling missing rows with nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

to the dataframe `df1`

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[2,4,5],[3,6,7],[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[2,6,7]],columns=['day','d','c'],index=[32,32,32,44,55,55])
print(df1)
    day  d  c
32    1  2  3
32    2  4  5
32    3  6  7
44    1  2  3
55    1  4  5
55    2  6  7
```

I would like to add as many rows as necessary in order to have for each index the column days that goes **from 1 to 5**. **The other columns should be filled with NaN starting from day 1**

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,np.nan,np.nan],[2,np.nan,np.nan],[3,2,3],[4,4,5],[5,6,7],
                       [1,np.nan,np.nan],[2,np.nan,np.nan],[3,np.nan,np.nan],[4,np.nan,np.nan],[5,2,3],
                       [1,np.nan,np.nan],[2,np.nan,np.nan],[3,np.nan,np.nan],[4,4,5],[5,6,7]],
                       columns=['day','d','c'],index=[32,32,32,32,32,44,44,44,44,44,55,55,55,55,55])
print(df2)
    day    d    c
32    1  NaN  NaN
32    2  NaN  NaN
32    3  2.0  3.0
32    4  4.0  5.0
32    5  6.0  7.0
44    1  NaN  NaN
44    2  NaN  NaN
44    3  NaN  NaN
44    4  NaN  NaN
44    5  2.0  3.0
55    1  NaN  NaN
55    2  NaN  NaN
55    3  NaN  NaN
55    4  4.0  5.0
55    5  6.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
N = 5
def f(x):
    x = x.astype(float)
    x.index = range(N + 1 - len(x), N + 1)
    return x.reindex(range(1, N + 1))

df1 = df1.groupby(level=0)['d','c'].apply(f).rename_axis((None, 'day')).reset_index(level=1)
print (df1)
    day    d    c
32    1  NaN  NaN
32    2  NaN  NaN
32    3  2.0  3.0
32    4  4.0  5.0
32    5  6.0  7.0
44    1  NaN  NaN
44    2  NaN  NaN
44    3  NaN  NaN
44    4  NaN  NaN
44    5  2.0  3.0
55    1  NaN  NaN
55    2  NaN  NaN
55    3  NaN  NaN
55    4  4.0  5.0
55    5  6.0  7.0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. The days should go from 1 to 5 so also the first index is not complete....